# Open GUI programs on Desktop machine's $DISPLAY reliably via SSH from server

Tags: ssh, desktop-environments

### TL;DR

Is there a command that does: "Set up this terminal as if it was started from the Desktop", so I can run commands as if I started them inside my desktop session when I ssh into my desktop machine?

### Details

When on a a server, I can ssh into my desktop machine (e.g. Xubuntu 18.04).

To run a simple `xterm` I can get away with just:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

(or `:1.0` on some machines)

To get `xdg-open https://askubuntu.com` to work I also need:

```
export XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/etc/xdg:/etc/xdg
```

I bet there are programs where I need to set up one or more of these other environment variables:

```
CLUTTER_BACKEND=x11
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1248/bus
GLADE_MODULE_PATH=:
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0
SESSION_MANAGER=local/kosh:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1931,unix/kosh:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1931
VTE_VERSION=5202
WINDOWID=79691779
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/etc/xdg:/etc/xdg
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/usr/share
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=xfce-
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1248
XDG_SEAT=seat0
XDG_SESSION_ID=3
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
```

Is there a command I can run after I've ssh-ed to my desktop machine that does:

"Set up all the environment variables e.g. correct `$DISPLAY` and `$XDG_CONFIG_DIRS` and what ever else might be required, as if this terminal was started from the Desktop"?

Instead of me having to experimentally and gradually discover which of the above envs are required by miscellaneous programs...

(Kudos to those that spot I'm - still - a [Babylon 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5) fan)